# Updating same value in firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there is a way for Firebase Cloud functions to detect that data is updated with same previous value in the same node ?

(without sending booleans varibles when updating the data)
thanks!

Comment: Do you want to act on the duplicate value or ignore it?

Comment: I would like to act on the duplicate .. i have a temperature sensor that changes same node evrytime and a firebase function that calculates the average .. But when the sensor sends same value it will not be detected

Comment: Why do you think that writing the same value will not fire an event?

Comment: i'm asking what is that event if it exists.. But i think that when a device is about to write a value it checks if that value exists or not ..

Comment: Firebase fires an event on ALL childAdded, childChanged or childRemoved events regardless if they exist or not. The only thing that would prevent an event from firing is if Rules were in place that prevented that write.

Answer (score 1):

If your Cloud Function is triggered from for example the Firebase Realtime Database, it is passed a `DeltaSnapshot` that contains both the previous state of the modified location and the new state.

Check out the [Firebase document on reading the previous value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value) for full details.

Comment: I think that in my case firebase don't even react to the update..
For exemple : I have a random number for some temperature .. and then I send the same value to the database.. how to detect that event?

Comment: That largely depends on how you send the value to the database to begin with. The Cloud Functions documentation has a great section on [responding to database events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). If you're having trouble making it work, please update your question to include the [minimum code that completely reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).